# How to convert a nested list of tibbles to a list of data.frames in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have nested list of tibbles and would like to convert it to a list of data.frames

```
starwars %>% select(homeworld , species , birth_year ) %>% nest_by(homeworld, .keep = F) %>% .$data
```

So in the example above there would be 49 data.frames in a list. How can I do this? It is important that the resulting list must be data.frames not tibbles, as the function I am using only accepts data.frames.

Comment: Once you have a list of tibbles, just call `as.data.frame` on them, e.g. using `purrr::map` or `lapply`

Comment: This was the correct answer. I had tried %>% data.frame() but it makes sense I needed lapply. Shame the question was closed otherwise I would had upvoted.

Comment: You can still upvote an answer on a closed question

Comment: I've upvoted your comment but it isn't written as an answer

Comment: No, I didn't post it as an answer because this needed to be marked as a duplicate instead

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help

```
starwars %>%
 select(homeworld , species , birth_year ) %>%
 group_split(homeworld)
```

Comment: `group_split(homeworld, .keep = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks, but the nested list still remains in tibbles